# Combining same elements into a list

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to convert my list

```
alist = [[1,[1,2]],[2,[3,4,5]],[3,[1,2]],[4,[3,4,5]],[5,[5,6,7]],[6,[1,2]]]
```

into this. Since the second item of those two sublists are same.

```
[[[1,3,6],[1,2]],[[2,4],[3,4,5]]]
```

This is my code

```
alist = [[1,[1,2]],[2,[3,4,5]],[3,[1,2]],[4,[3,4,5]],[5,[5,6,7]],[6,[1,2]]]
lst=[]
for i in range(len(alist)):
    inner = []
    inner1=[]
    for j in range(i+1,len(alist)):
        if i+1 < len(alist):
            if alist[i][1] == alist[j][1]:
                inner1.append(alist[i][0])
                inner1.append(alist[j][0])
                inner.append(inner1)
                inner.append(alist[i][1])
                lst.append(inner)


print(lst)
```

but it gives this instead

```
[[[1, 3, 1, 6], [1, 2], [1, 3, 1, 6], [1, 2]], [[1, 3, 1, 6], [1, 2], [1, 3, 1, 6], [1, 2]], [[2, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[3, 6], [1, 2]]]
```

It works when there's only 2 elements that are the same but when there's 3 it doesn't work. 
Example

```
[2,4],[3,4,5] #2 of the same elements from alist works
[1,3,1,6],[1,2] #3 of the same elements from alist doesn't work
```

Can anyone please offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict (an `Ordered` one since you have to maintain the order) to group "heads" by "tails":

```
alist = [[1,[1,2]],[2,[3,4,5]],[3,[1,2]],[4,[3,4,5]],[5,[5,6,7]],[6,[1,2]]]

from collections import OrderedDict

c = OrderedDict()

for head, tail in alist:
    c.setdefault(tuple(tail), []).append(head)

res = [[heads, list(tail)] for tail, heads in c.items()]
print res
```

prints

```
[[[1, 3, 6], [1, 2]], [[2, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[5], [5, 6, 7]]]
```

If you want to omit `5` (a group with a single "head"), add a condition to the `res=` line:

```
res = [[heads, list(tail)] for tail, heads in c.items() if len(heads) > 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) So sorry if I made it sound complicated I don't really know explain my question.

Comment: @Hal: no problem ;)